# Using electron-forge and vite for development, How to reload the electron app when main.js change?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

The official say that use webpack could reload successfully. But my frontend use vite so how could I reload the whole app when main.js change without config the renderer.js by webpack?
my project is like:

```
frontend
-- package.json
-- vite.config.js
-- index.html
-- main.js
client
-- package.json
-- electron-forge.config.js
-- main.js
-- preload.js
```

To use vite to open an frontend and use electron-forge to start an electron app.

How could I reload the electron app when my main.js or preload.js changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Hot Reloading in Electron-Vite](https://%3E%20https://electron-vite.org/guide/hot-reloading)

## Enable Hot Reloading

There are two ways to enable it:

- Use CLI option -w or --watch, e.g. electron-vite dev --watch. This is the preferred way, it's more flexible.
- Use configuration option build.watch and set to {}. In addition, more watcher options can be configured, see WatcherOptions.

> EXAMPLE: If someone needs help setting up a watcher via Vite.js JavaScript API, here is a [boilerplate](https://github.com/projektorius96/vite-build/blob/main/README.md)

## When to use hot reloading

Because the timing of reloading is uncontrollable, hot reloading cannot be perfectly implemented. In practice, hot reloading is not always beneficial，so it is recommended to use the CLI option to flexibly decide whether to enable or not.

## Summary

- In `package.json`, find `script` section and add: `"dev:watch": "electron-vite dev --watch"`, after which is should look like:

```js
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "electron-vite dev",
    "dev:watch": "electron-vite dev --watch",
    ...
  },
```

I personally suggest using `--watch` when you're working intensively with  main process or preload scripts modules, because vite can still reload most of the components without using this, and this hot-reload will reset all the states and restart the whole app, which is inconvenient when working with states (e.g Redux) or front-end stuff (e.g. UI with CSS).